# Using one specific value per group to every other value in group

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a specific programming question concerning R.
I want to apply a custom function over a whole data set, but the values in the function should change compared to what group it belongs to. Here is a dataset that is similar to the one i'm working with

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("one", 10), rep("two", 9), rep("three", 11)),
         slot = c(1:10, 1:9, 1:11),
         x = sample(100, 30))
```

And the function

```
RI_fun <- function(x, y) {
((x - y)/ y) * 100
}
```

The real dataset is larger but the structure is the same. A little info on the real dataset: It is a series of measurements(slots) on a sample (group) where i want the first measurement (slot == 1) to be y in the custom function (RI_fun)

i want to make a new column that is the output of the custom function where x = df$x and y is the x value where df$slot == 1 to each group.

I have tried to make a for loop, but without success. My idea was to make the y value an if else statement where it checked for df$group and applied df$x where slot == 1 and group == group that has just been checked.

Here is my attemp:

```
for (i in seq_along(df$group)) {
RI[i] = RI_fun(x = df$x[i],
               y = (ifelse(df$group == df$group[i],
                           df$x[df$slot == 1 & df$group == df$group[i]],
                           NA)))
```

However the output is:

```
[1]   0.00000 172.41379  41.37931 196.55172 213.79310 -82.75862  72.41379 186.20690  75.86207  44.82759        NA
[12]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[23]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

When i manually checked what the output should be, it showed that the for-loop is correct up to [11] where it doesn't work anymore. I've tried some other for-loops that are similar to this one, but this is the one where i got closest to the desired output.

Any help you got would be appreciated. If i wasn't clear enough, please ask and i'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: can you show the desired output? use `set.seed()` to make it reproducible..

Comment: I'll edit that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and nicely formatted with reproducible example! Kudos!

In R, you generally don't need to bother using loops. R is inherently vectorized, so we can express ourselves in terms of vectors. Moving along to data.frames, the idea is the same, and adding the package `dplyr`, we get some easy functionality.

First, I demonstrate what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(y=x[slot==1])
as.data.frame(.Last.value)
   group slot  x  y
1    one    1 30 30
2    one    2 72 30
3    one    3 88 30
4    one    4  5 30
5    one    5 55 30
6    one    6 42 30
7    one    7 11 30
8    one    8 53 30
9    one    9 73 30
10   one   10 87 30
11   two    1 52 52
12   two    2 82 52
13   two    3 78 52
14   two    4 59 52
15   two    5 12 52
16   two    6 95 52
17   two    7  1 52
18   two    8 70 52
19   two    9 66 52
20 three    1 69 69
21 three    2 79 69
22 three    3 80 69
23 three    4 21 69
24 three    5 94 69
25 three    6 75 69
26 three    7 25 69
27 three    8 15 69
28 three    9 74 69
29 three   10 31 69
30 three   11 43 69
```

So, we can confirm that we get the correct `x` and `y` values. Try to remove the line `group_by` and see what happens.

Satisfied that we are obtaining the relevant `x` and `y` values, plug in your function:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(RI=RI_fun(x, x[slot==1]))
```

If you did try to remove the `group_by` line, you got an error. That's because `mutate` wants to use a value, either 1 for the entire vector (column) or a value per element in the column. So what happens if you have multiple slots == 1 per group? Well, you'll have to decide how to deal with the deviation from your requirements.

***EDIT:***

The reason your for-loop isn't working as expected is due to the `ifelse` at y. Simply replace with

```
for (i in seq_along(df$group)) {
RI[i] = RI_fun(x = df$x[i],
               y = df$x[df$slot == 1 & df$group == df$group[i]])
}
```

and it should work just fine.

This is due to `ifelse` is vectorized; for each element in the test (first) argument (`df$group == df$group[i]`) it returns the corresponding element in either the yes (second) or no (third) element.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explaination on using dplyr instead and the answer to why my for-loop wasn't working. I'll definetly try using dplyr instead for similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the ifelse statement. When you call ifelse(df$group == df$group[i] ...), it returns false as soon as df$group[i] != df$group[1]; it returns the result of the very first comparison. You don't need the ifelse, as far as I can see. The following code worked for me (though you should do the manual check to make sure that it's correct).

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("one", 10), rep("two", 9), rep("three", 11)),
                 slot = c(1:10, 1:9, 1:11),
                 x = sample(100, 30))

RI_fun <- function(x, y) {
  ((x - y)/ y) * 100
}

RI <- rep(NA, 30)

for (i in seq_along(df$group)) {
  RI[i] = RI_fun(x = df$x[i],
                 y = (df$x[df$slot == 1 & df$group == df$group[i]]))
}

RI
```